# How to make a webpage linked to spotify?

Tags: spotify

I just want to create a simple page with a search bar and result table linked to Spotify.
Any examples?

Answer (score 0):

have you looked at the api for spotify?

These are the available services of lookup and search

You can find examples here

https://developer.spotify.com/technologies/web-api/